# The if condition only works with an alert and the position is reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code is that the player goes to where the user clicks, but now I want the character to look at the X axis where it goes.
The problem is that it only works when you have an alert, but only if the alert gives an error because if the alert does not give an error it does not work.
The other problem is that the transform translate3d is deleted then the player returns to the same position although the scaleX changes.

I'm new to jquery and I have no idea.

```
$(document).on("click mousedown", "#Park", function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var newposX = x - 60;
    var newposY = y - 60;
    var n = $(".circle").offset()
    if (newposX < n.left) {
        $(".circle").css("transform", "scaleX(-1)");
        alert(ok)
    }
    $(".circle").css("transform", "translate3d(" + newposX + "px," + newposY + "px,0px)");

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".circle3").css("display", "none");
        $(".circle2").css("display", "block");
    }, 2000);
    $(".circle2").css("display", "none");
    $(".circle3").css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after the conditional, you're overwriting the `transform` with a new value, which means the `scaleX()` is immediately overwritten unless your code breaks at the `alert()`.

Instead, write your conditional like this, to ensure the `scaleX()` doesn't get overwritten when you set the `translate3d()`:

```
if (newposX < n.left) {
    $(".circle").css("transform", "scaleX(-1) translate3d(" + newposX + "px," + newposY + "px,0px)");
} else {
    $(".circle").css("transform", "translate3d(" + newposX + "px," + newposY + "px,0px)");
}
```

Alternatively, you could write it like this, which is easier to read in my opinion:

```
let transform = `translate3d(${newposX}px, ${newposY}px, 0px)`;
if (newposX < n.left) {
    transform = 'scaleX(-1) ' + transform;
}
$('.circle').css('transform', transform);
```

Comment: the position Y is solved but the X isn't solved. the object in X goes far when using scaleX

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of `scaleX()` and `translate3d()` within the `transform`?